# How do you print the last observation of a SAS data set?

Tags: sas

I have a data set with 1000 observations. I want to only print out the last observation. Using the following:

```
proc print data=apple(firstobs = 1000 obs = 1000); 
run;
```

I can get the last observation. But I have to know in advance that my data set has 1000 observations. How do I do this without knowing this?

Comment: Hi Trevor, the question "how to get the number of observations in a dataset" has been answered here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658994/how-to-detect-whether-a-data-set-has-no-observations-in-sas

Comment: a heads up for anyone who is studying for the SAS Base test and ended up here -- don't fall for their tricks -- there is no such thing as a LASTOBS option!  :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many ways you could do this. Here are two:

```
proc sql noprint;
 select n(var1) into :nobs
 from apple;
quit;

proc print data=apple(firstobs=&nobs); run;
```

This just reads the number of observations into a macro variable, and then use that to specify the first observation. (Note that `var1` refers to a variable in your data.)

Another approach would be to create a data view that only keeps the last observation and then print that:

```
data tmp / view=tmp;
 set apple nobs=nobs;
 if _n_=nobs;
run;

proc print data=tmp; run;
```

Answer (score 3):

I think that the `end` option for the `SET`, `MERGE`, `MODIFY`, or `UPDATE` statement is very useful.

```
data x;
  do i = 1 to 1000;
    output;
  end;
run;

data x;
  set x end = _end;
  end = _end;
proc print data = x;
  where end;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to find the number of observations; the following macro is one example.

```
%macro nobs (dsn);
   %let nobs=0;
   %let dsid = %sysfunc(open(&dsn));
   %if &dsid %then %let nobs = %sysfunc(attrn(&dsid,nobs));
   %let rc   = %sysfunc(close(&dsid));
   &nobs
%mend nobs;

%let n = %nobs(apple);

proc print data=apple (firstobs=&n obs=&n); run;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two simple solutions:

Solution 1:

```
data result;
    set apple end=end;
    if end then output;
run;
proc print data=result;
run;
```

Solution 2:

```
data result;
    set apple nobs=nobs;
    if _N_=nobs then output;
run;
proc print data=result;
run;
```