# Getting last row of table in SAS SQL

Tags: sql, sas

Hello I am doing the following data step where I extract the last line of a table.
How can I do the same in a `proc sql`, I am hoping it will be much quicker if I can access directly the last row?

```
data refTable;
    set vhd(keep= v69c1ec v69dhec v69nbms fixing where=(fixing = 'continu')) end=eof;
    if eof then output;
    by v69dhec v69nbms;
run;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible to reproduce this behavior in SQL.  There is no natural sense of "row order" in SQL.  Note that you are **NOT** accessing the "last line of a table"; you are getting the last qualifying row **after** the application of a `WHERE` clause.

If you really were getting the last row, a much faster SAS technique would be to use the `POINT=` and `NOBS=` options, something like this:

```
data refTable;
    get_me = nobs;
    set vhd(keep=v69c1ec v69dhec v69nbms fixing) point=get_me nobs=nobs;
    output;
    stop;
run;
```

Notice this only works if you do **NOT** include a `WHERE` clause!

Comment: What if you use the `firstobs` and `obs` statements are used as data set options in your `proc sql` statement?  Does `proc sql` honor these or ignore them when dealing with SAS datasets?

Comment: @RobPenridge Yes, the `FIRSTOBS=` and `OBS=` options are honored during `PROC SQL` processing, but they aren't relevant to the question asked.  Also, their meaning is foggy (to me) when there are `WHERE` clauses present; I rarely use either option myself.

Comment: Ah good point - I didn't see the where clause in the original question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you cannot access the last row using `proc sql` directly.  The process would be to order the data and then choose the first row, using `outobs = 1`.

This question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7957138/how-do-you-print-the-last-observation-of-a-sas-data-set) explains how to get the last row efficiently in SAS.  Basically, ask SAS how many records are in the data set and then skip ahead directly to that one.