# How do I identify a dataset with no observations? For an IF statement

Tags: sas

I need to identify if a dataset has no observations so I can create an IF statement later to ignore it. Any ideas??

Open to proc SQL, but I don't understand it.

Comment: Have you checked this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658994/how-to-detect-how-many-observations-in-a-dataset-or-if-it-is-empty-in-sas?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

If a dataset has 0 observations, a set statement will not run. So, what I do is to create a macrovariable that is set only if the SET statement has been run, like this:
`%let doesItExist=NO;`
`data _null_;`
`set theDataset;`
`call symput("doesItExist","YES");`
`stop;`
`run;`
`%put &doesItExist;`