# Get server info for all librefs

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

How can I get a table with variables `libref` and `server_id` (or any server info) for all libraries available to me in `SAS`?

My goal is to get a summary of where the data is physically located for all these libraries, in order to write efficient queries when fetching data from different servers.

Comment: If your libref is a meta engine you could use this macro to generate a direct connection and examine that to find your actual source:  https://github.com/Boemska/macrocore/blob/master/meta/mm_assigndirectlib.sas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at what information is available in the view SASHELP.VLIBNAM (or DICTIONARY.LIBNAMES when using PROC SQL).

Here is a utility macro that pulls the engine, host and schema from that view for a given libref. I have used it for TERADATA, ORACLE and ODBC engines.  [dblibchk.sas](https://github.com/sasutils/macros/blob/master/dblibchk.sas)

Comment: Thanks Tom, you save me once more

Answer (score 1):

From Tom's code and advices I built the table I needed with this code:

```
PROC SQL;
SELECT distinct libname, engine, path,
CASE WHEN engine in('BASE','V9') THEN 'SAS' ELSE catx('_',engine,path) END AS server
FROM DICTIONARY.LIBNAMES ;
QUIT;
```

Answer (score 1):

there are a few tables that can help you in the Library SASHELP like Tom mentioned.
You can also use VTABLE will have all the tables from which library and VCOLUMN will have the detail from library to table to columns as well as the data type used and it's length.
They work a bit like in SQL data from the information_schema database.

Alternatively using proc content on a dataset will also return all of it's component and you can put that in a table or a macro variable.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Oh I tought you needed more details than just the server path :)